# PHP reduced value from another input value

Tags: php

I want make value of input from another input value,
 so if i add number in first input,
 second input is reduced from first input,
 can someone help me...

```
$value1 = 10;
echo "<input type='text' value='$value2'></input>";
$value3 = $value1 - $value2;
echo "<input type='text' value='$value3'></input>";
```

Comment: Could you please show us an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript for that kind problem it easy to handle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="val2" id='val2' oninput="loadVal3(this.value)">
<input type="text" name="val3" id='val3'>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadVal3(val) {
        let val1=10;
        if(!isNaN(val)&&val!=""){
            document.getElementById('val3').value=val1-val;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('val3').value="";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// i use the REQUEST  HTTP Request variables (is can changed by GET Or Post request
$secoundVarible = $_REQUEST['value'];

$staticValue = 10;
function reduceValue($num1,$num2){
  return $result = $num1 - $num2;

 }

 $reducedValue = reduceValue($staticValue, $secoundVarible);
echo "<input type='text' value='$reducedValue'></input>";
```